# Unable to install Adhoc Distribution iPA Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

I created new distribution certificate and added my device UDID, and then created Adhoc provisioning profile that contains my device UDID using distribution certificate that created right now.
I think there is not any wrong in this step.

After that, I made new iOS build(from Xamarin Forms project) with above certificate and provisioning and save Adhoc ipa to my MAC.
I tried to copy it to my device via itunes 12.7 but it's failed to install it.
It shows me following error message "Unable to install [App Name]."

So I tried to download that ipa from Diawi but it's also failed and shows me "Unable to download, please try again later".

I have been trying to fix this issue for full 2 weeks but I couldn't find any solution.
Please help me to fix if someone faced same issue in the past.
Any suggestions are also much appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hit your diawi link in Mac's Safari browser and check whether your Device ID is present in build. You can check in Provisioning Devices section.

Comment: Do u have pushnotification enabled

Comment: yes, Both in project entitlement and app setting in developer portal.

Comment: Finally and after a lot of trouble I was able to fix this issue.

I'm working with Xamarin. The issue appeared after enabling push notifications for my app causing the provisioning profiles to become damaged.

I unchecked push notifications from entitlements.plist (doesn't disable push notifications)

I was cleaning the project and removing profiles all the way.. Look this one

Comment: wow, you are very very close to my issue, Absolutely I tried to create new project and tested with same certificate and provisioning, it was working good but it showed same error after I enabled push notification in entitlement. Then one question, the push notification will still work after I disable push notification in entitlements.plist?

Comment: You need to check it

Comment: Check what? When checking it in entitlement.plist, it has that issue. but when disabling it, issue has gone. what is your opinion?

Comment: He meant you need to check if the push notifications still work if you disable push notifications in the entitelements.plst. I had the same issue where the ipa file wasn't installing because I had enabled push notifications. If you disable push notifications then you won't get any notifications. I am still trying to figure out how to do an ad-hoc distribution with push notifications enabled so I can test if they work.